# JavaScript image never finishes .onload

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, onload

New user here.

I am making a hockey game using JavaScript, and I need all of the images to finish loading before the main function is called to avoid flickering.

There are four images used: skaterAmin.png, skaterBmin.png, goalieAmin.png, goalieBmin.png

I am getting stuck on 2 out of 4 `.onload` functions.

both `loadSkaterImgA` and `loadSkaterImgB` will change to `true` but both `loadGoalieImgA` and `loadGoalieImgB` remain `false`

also used `console.log()` to confirm they were actually stuck

I also double checked all image src's and they are correct

```
//load images before main draw function to avoid flickering

var loadSkaterImgA = false;
var loadGoalieImgA = false;
var loadSkaterImgB = false;
var loadGoalieImgB = false;

function preloadSkaterImgA() {
    var skaterImgA = new Image();
    skaterImgA.onload = function() {
        completeSkaterImgA();
        return;
    }
    skaterImgA.src = 'skaterAmin.png';
    return skaterImgA;
}

function preloadGoalieImgA() {
    var goalieImgA = new Image();
    goalieImgA.onload = function() {
        completeGoalieImgA();
        return;
    }
    goalieImgA = 'goalieAmin.png';
    return goalieImgA;
}

function preloadSkaterImgB(){
    var skaterImgB = new Image();
    skaterImgB.onload = function() {
        completeSkaterImgB();
        return;
    }
    skaterImgB.src = 'skaterBmin.png';
    return skaterImgB;
}

function preloadGoalieImgB(){
    var goalieImgB = new Image();
    goalieImgB.onload = function() {
        completeGoalieImgB();
        return;
    }
    goalieImgB = 'goalieBmin.png';
    return goalieImgB;
}

function completeSkaterImgA(){
    loadSkaterImgA = true;
    return loadSkaterImgA;
}

function completeGoalieImgA(){
    loadGoalieImgA = true;
    return loadGoalieImgA;
}

function completeSkaterImgB(){
    loadSkaterImgB = true;
    return loadSkaterImgB;
}

function completeGoalieImgB(){
    loadGoalieImgB = true;
    return loadGoalieImgB;
}

preloadSkaterImgA();
preloadGoalieImgA();
preloadSkaterImgB();
preloadGoalieImgB();
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: You need to set `src` for your goalies.

Comment: Or, more specifically: `goalieImgA = 'goalieAmin.png';` should be `goalieImgA.src = 'goalieAmin.png';` (and so on for Goalie B)

Comment: thanks, thought it was probably a small syntax mistake

Comment: problem solved, sorry dont know how to close thread

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call your preload methods after the DOM (which waits until all images are loaded) has loaded:

```
window.onload = function () { 
    preloadSkaterImgA();
    preloadGoalieImgA();
    preloadSkaterImgB();
    preloadGoalieImgB();
 }
```